# Unable to Compile openGL code in dev c++

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut, freeglut

Currently I am trying to compile code below which was a part of my academic activities

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>
int main()
{
    glutCreateWindow("first graphics window");  
}
```

but It is constantly showing these 3 errors:

> "c:\program files
> (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   cannot find -lbgi"
> "C:\Users\Tayyab\Documents\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit
> status"
> "C:\Users\Tayyab\Documents\Makefile.win   recipe for target '"glut' failed"

and I have no idea what is wronge in my code.
I watched a video tutorial to resolve above issue so I have inserted following files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\GL" directory:

> freeglut.h
>
> free_ext.h
>
> freeglut_std.h
>
> glut.h

and also

> libfreeglut.a
>
> libfreeglut_static.a

in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" directory

moreover I have also inserted

> freeglut.dll

in "C:\Windows\System32" directory.

But there was no benefit of doing all these insertions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ I dont think this question is a duplicate of the question you mentioned as there is no answer for my problem in that post.

Comment: This is a duplicated and that post answers your question. Read it carefully.

Comment: still cant find my answer there. no answer in that question explained answer to the errors which I am getting and are mentioned above. Can u please write here specific answer to solve the errors which I am getting? @Fredrik